# SignalR is not be able to connect on aspx webform

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, signalr

I want to use signalR on a .net framework 4.6.2 webform project, However, after tried 4 days, my connection always stope at /signalr/negotiate/, response is 400

here is my webconfig

```
<httpProtocol>
    <customHeaders>
        <remove name="X-Powered-By" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="POST,GET,OPTIONS,PUT,DELETE" />
    </customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>
```

This is my startup code

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
{
  app.Map("/signalr", map =>
  {
      map.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll);
      var hubConfiguration = new HubConfiguration{};
      map.RunSignalR(hubConfiguration);
  });
}
```

this is a code sample from my aspx page

```
<script src="scripts/jquery-1.6.4.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery.signalR-2.4.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="signalr/hubs"></script>

<script>
$(function(){

        var logger = $.connection.idologyHub;
        logger.client.logMessage = function (msg) {
            console.log(msg);
        };
        $.connection.hub.start();
})
</script>
```

This is my hub class

```
public class IdologyHub:Hub 
{

    public static readonly System.Timers.Timer _Timer = new 
    System.Timers.Timer();

    static IdologyHub()
    {
        _Timer.Interval = 5000;
        _Timer.Elapsed += TimerElapsed;
        _Timer.Start();
    }

    static void TimerElapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        var hub = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext("IdologyHub");
        hub.Clients.All.logMessage(string.Format("{0} - Still running", 
        DateTime.UtcNow));
    }
}
```

I have checked online, people rarely talk about how to run signalR with aspx webforms, plus the sample code they had is not working with my project
Also, I am also be aware the cors is needed for this case. plus I did work with signal R in web API/MVC, but seems it is very different in webforms, thank you  for the help.

Comment: Why do you think that CORS is involved? Is the hub hosted on a different site than your Web Forms app?

Comment: Also did you check the browser developer console for CORS-related or other issues? If so, post them.

Comment: @mason No, the host is not host on a different site, it is just some other information I checked, can't remember the link, someone says, the owin cors have do be set. Sorry, I can't find the link.

Comment: @Rex Henderson No, there is no cors related issue, it is basically, just fail at $.connection.hub.start()

Comment: As the name suggests, Cross Origin Resource Sharing (CORS) applies when you do a request from the code that runs in the browser context (such as client side JavaScript) and it makes a request to a different host other than the page you're on. If you're trying to make a connection to a hub hosted on the same site your page was served on, then CORS does not apply, and you don't need any CORS specific logic added to your app. So you're saying that the connection fails at `$.connection.hub.start()`. What does your browser's JavaScript console tell you about it? How do you know it failed?

Comment: @mason it says: jquery-1.11.0.min.js:14 GET http://localhost:50000/signalr/negotiate/ 400 (Bad Request), Protocol error: Unknown transport.

Comment: "jquery-1.11.0.min.js" error but above it shows you loading 1.6.4.js. If you are loading 2 different version that is a problem in itself.

Comment: If you navigate your browser to `<your site>/signalr/hubs` what do you get?

Comment: @mason I get the script

Comment: your code is working for me. I am using jQuery 3.6.0 though

Comment: Okay. So that tells us that SignalR is configured at `<your site>/signalr/hubs` but that your page is having trouble loading it. My guess is your script tag declarations aren't relative to the same location. It would also explain why you're showing us one version of jQuery but the error seems to be coming from another. This .aspx page you're accessing - is it at the root of your site? In IIS are you using a virtual app to run this site? Are there any other failed requests when you look at the network tab of your browser's developer tools?

Comment: popped in jquery 1.6.4 and it is still working for me exactly as you posted you code. You did not provide the signalr/hub script so my project fails to load that.

Comment: @mason, yes, the page where I am access it , is not my master page or default.aspx, it is a seperate child page, also, I have removed Jquery 1.6 since it cause other issues, as well, we are using jquery 1.11. and there are no other failed requests

Comment: When you say child page, is it at the root of the site? Or is it in a subfolder?

Comment: you can check your implementation against mine here https://github.com/ditchcode/JquerySignalRTesting

Comment: @mason, I tried in the master page, still same error, same issue. it is the child of a master page, where I want to call the connection.

Comment: Okay, you can be a "child of a master page" but still be in the root folder. What I'm curious about is whether your page is in the root folder or not, I don't really care about master pages. The reason it's important is that the path to the generated hub location `<your site>/signalr/hubs` needs to line up with where your page says it's at in your script tag. You used a path relative to the current folder, and that's going to break if the page is not in the root, because the `/signalr` segment is off the root, not off a subfolder.

Comment: @mason, I believe my page is inside the root folder. Also, signalr/hubs path did not show 404 not fount